# No C++ Project Properties in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

We have installed Visual Studio 2015 on a new PC.

When we select the project properties for a C++ project, the dialog shows code-analysis properties, but no other project properties.

[image]

We have already run a 'repair' installation, but the problem persists.

Does anybody know this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I could only catch this link [**HERE**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/07/29/developing-for-windows-10-with-visual-c-2015/) because I am on the mobile right now. So you need to install C++ kit for your Visual Studio. Then you will be able to see and create all its projects

Answer (score 0):

I have meet the same issue after I add an existing visuall c++ 2010 poject o Visual C++ 2015 solution. I solved it by this way:

Right Click on the poject, Select "Upgrade VC++ Compiler and Libraries", after upgrade, every thing is OK.[image]